# Ошибка при подключении к mysql в android приложении, используя mysql connector

Tags: android, kotlin, jdbc, mysqlconnector

Установил mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar и переместил в папку libs, дальше -> add as library
Но при попытке подключения к моей базе данных выдается ошибка **java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.**
Так же пробовал менять версии mysql connector, ошибка остается.
Я новичок в разработке в android и не совсем понимаю, что делаю не так. Ниже приведен код из MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.sravnivatel

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import java.sql.DriverManager

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding : ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")

        val url = "jdbc:mysql://db4free.net:3306/dbproducts?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL&serverTimezone=GMT"
        val login = "user"
        val password = "password"

        var connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, password)

        }

    }
```

Вся ошибка:

```js
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.sravivatel, PID: 16382
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sravivatel/com.example.sravivatel.MainActivity}: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:108)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:95)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:87)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:1035)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:852)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:444)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:230)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:226)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:580)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:218)
    at com.example.sravivatel.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:30)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8595)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8573)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1456)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3764)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971) 
Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1675)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:115)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1152)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:150)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:66)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:152)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:982)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:852) 
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:444) 
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:230) 
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:226) 
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:580) 
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:218) 
    at com.example.sravivatel.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:30) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8595) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8573) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1456) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3764) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
```

Comment: Так вы Android Studio к MySQL подключаете, или все таки свое собственное Андроид-приложение?

Comment: Здравствуйте, я подключаю собственное приложение

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный стектрейс ошибки из Logcat.

Comment: У вас же банальный `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Нельзя делать сетевые запросы из UI потока. Но и даже после этого не уверен что `mysql-connector-java` будет работать в виртуальной машине Android.